# Array forEach pass "push" as argument

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, lambda

Faced strange issue in JS. I receive error on this:

```
let a = []
let b = [1,2,3]
b.forEach(a.push)
TypeError: Array.prototype.push called on null or undefined
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at repl:1:3
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:262:27)
    at bound (domain.js:287:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:431:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:211:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:550:8)
```

Sure, I've made a suggestion, that the context is lost. So, I try to accomplish that in this way:

```
b.forEach([].push.bind(a))
```

The result becomes unpredictable:

```
[ 1, 0, [ 1, 2, 3 ], 2, 1, [ 1, 2, 3 ], 3, 2, [ 1, 2, 3 ] ]
```

WHAT? =) Where is 0 from? Okay, maybe its "glitch"-index, but why not first than? :)

Just to make it clear, this works in a classical way, and that's not a question:

```
b.forEach(el => a.push(el) )
```

Can someone explain this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically as per the standard syntax of [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), it is having 3 different parameters, `current item`, `index` and the `array` over which the forEach is called. So `push` function which was bound with `a` will be called every time with those parameters. That is the issue here.

```
iteration 1 : a.push(1,0,[1,2,3]) //since a was bound with push
iteration 2 : a.push(2,1,[1,2,3])
iteration 3 : a.push(3,2,[1,2,3])
```

Your code will be executed like above.

Comment: Long story short: OP shot himself in the foot trying to write "smart" code. Lesson: Avoid writing "smart" code. :)

Comment: Thanks, I shouldn't miss this.

Answer (score 0):

Because `.forEach()` supplies to your callback 3 arguments.

> callback is invoked with three arguments:
>
> 1. the element value
> 2. the element index
> 3. the array being traversed

The `.push()` can accept any number of arguments. So, on each iteration, `.push()` adds those three arguments to your array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this became even clearer now.